# How to check if any array members can be sum up to the largest of them in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

The goal is to create a function that takes an array of numbers as a parameter and checks *if the largest of them can be obtained as the sum of any of the other numbers* in the array.

One condition is that negative numbers can be a part of the array taken as a parameter.

#### The problem

The function I came up with sums *all* the array members except the largest, instead of summing *any of them*. This is why it fails, as can be seen below

```js
function ArrayAddition(arr) {
  // Sort small to large
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  // get maximum number
  var max = arr.pop();
  
  // Sum
  var num = 0;
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    num += item
  });

  return max === num;
}

// Correctly return true
console.log(ArrayAddition([5,7,16,1,3]));

// Wronglly retuns false (5 - 2 + 8 = 11)  
console.log(ArrayAddition([2,5,-2,8,11]));
```

#### Question

How can I make it work if **any** array members sum up to the largest?

Comment: Sorting the array is unnecessary, you can find the largest number in just one iteration. I think you have to apply backtracking to this problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: @MihailFeraru Backtracking will only work for tiny problems. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem for a discussion of the standard dynamic programming method that solves this much more efficiently.

Comment: Can array members be used multiple times? Like, if input is [2, 3, 8], is that true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the max element from the array, the task now becomes given an array and a target sum(max element) find if there exists any sub-sequence in the array that sums up to the target sum. This problem is identical to the [Subset sum problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

The easiest way to solve this is to use the inclusion exclusion principle and solve it in `O(2^n)` as Mihail's answer already suggests. There are other ways to solve it more efficiently(have a look at the subset sum problem link)

In the below approach, instead of generating all possible subsets, we only consider the sums of all those subsets. This would save a lot of memory but, the worst time complexity still remains the same which is `O(2^n)`.

```js
function ArrayAddition(arr) {
  // Sort small to large
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  // get maximum number
  const max = arr.pop();

  // maintain a set of all possible sums
  const sums = new Set();

  // insert 0 into sums set i.e, sum of an empty set {}
  sums.add(0);

  for (const value of arr) {
    const newSums = new Set();

    for (const sum of sums) {
      // new possible sum if we consider the value in a subset
      const newSum = sum + value;

      // we have a subset whose sum is equal to max
      if (newSum === max)
        return true;

      newSums.add(newSum);
    }

    // insert all new possible sums
    for (const sum of newSums)
      sums.add(sum);
  }

  // no subset which adds up to max was found
  return false;
}

console.log(ArrayAddition([5, 7, 16, 1, 3]));

console.log(ArrayAddition([2, 5, -2, 8, 11]));
```

Explanation of the approach with an example

```
arr = [5,7,16,1,3]

after sorting and removing the max element we have

arr = [1,3,5,7]
max = 16

now initially the set 'sums' only has 0 (empty set)

sums = { 0 }

after the first iteration

sums = {0, 1} which is {[0], [0 +1]}

after the second iteration

sums = {0, 1, 3, 4} which is {[0], [0+1], [0 +3], [0+1 +3]}

after third iteration

sums = {0, 1, 3, 4, 
        5, 6, 8, 9}

after fourth iteration

sums = {0, 1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9
        7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16}

since 16 is a possible sum, we return true
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is one possible approach (and naive) using bitmasks to generate all subsets of a set. You should be able to use it for a correct solution. It will be a good exercise to optimize it further by reducing memory usage and early exiting.

```
function allSubsetsWithBitmasks(arr) {
    const n = arr.length;
    const subsets = [];
    
    // there are 2^n subsets for every set
    // every subset can be represented by n bits
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
        const subset = [];
        
        for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // if j-th bit is on, include arr[j] in the subset
            if (i & (1 << j)) subset.push(arr[j]);
        }
        
        subsets.push(subset);
    }
    
    return subsets;
}

console.log(allSubsetsWithBitmasks([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

I encourage you to also code the backtracking solution and also get rid of the .sort() because it introduces an unnecessary logarithmic factor. (sorts are made in `O(N log N)`).

Comment: Great work, but the function should return a boolean.

Comment: Why would you comment about an "unnecessary logarithmic factor" when this solution is O(n2ⁿ)?

Answer (score 1):

I like these kind of questions.. reminds me of the college years.  For this one, not sure why all these answers involve complicated sets and subsets.  The real question is "is there some sort of combination of numbers in an array, that when summed, equals the maximum number.

The solution below will use a recursive function to sum all combinations of the array. If it doesn't find a possible sum = max, it begins chopping elements out of the array one by one and checks each time if there is a combination that sums to the max.

** NOTE - Sorting array smallest to largest is absolutely necessary

```js
let arNum = [1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
console.log(canSumToLargest(arNum));

function canSumToLargest(arNum){
    let bCanSum = false;
  let nMax = arNum.sort((a, b) => a - b).pop();
  
  // traverse each element checking if it can sum to max
  arNum.forEach((ele, i) =>{
    let arTmp = arNum.slice();
    let nSum = arTmp.splice(i, 1)[0];
    // check for possible sum = max
    if(hasSum(arTmp, nMax, nSum, 0)){
      bCanSum = true;
      return false // jump out of foreach loop
    }
    // no max sum at this point. so begin removing numbers one by one
    else{
      for(let n = 0, nLen = arTmp.length; n < nLen; n++){
        arTmp.shift();
        if(hasSum(arTmp, nMax, nSum, 0)){
          bCanSum = true;
          return false // jump out of foreach loop
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return bCanSum
}

// recursive array summing function.
// sums all elements one by one until max found, or sum is larger than max, or reached end of array
function hasSum(arr, nMax, nSum, nNdx){
    if(nNdx == arr.length)
    return false
  
  nSum += arr[nNdx];
  
  if(nSum == nMax)
    return true
    
  return hasSum(arr, nMax, nSum, nNdx + 1)
}
```